# Display collection of nested objects in DataTables

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

```
[
{
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "/Date(1429653550233)/",
    "IssueList": null
},
{
    "name": "Tiger Nixon 1",
    "position": "System Architect 1",
    "salary": "$420,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "IssueList": [
        {
            "Number": 1,
            "IssueDate": "/Date(1429653550233)/",
            "Issue": "Lots of Problems"
        },
        {
            "Number": 2,
            "IssueDate": "/Date(1429185060000)/",
            "Issue": "Lots of Problems here too"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Tiger Nixon 2",
    "position": "System Architect 2",
    "salary": "$520,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "IssueList": [
        {
            "Number": 3,
            "IssueDate": "/Date(1429653550233)/",
            "Issue": "Lots of Problems"
        },
        {
            "Number": 4,
            "IssueDate": "/Date(1429185060000)/",
            "Issue": "Lots of Problems here too"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Tiger Nixon 3",
    "position": "System Architect 3",
    "salary": "$620,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "IssueList": null
}
```

]

I want to display the above JSON in "DataTables". The nested objects in the IssueList should be displayed as a child table inside the main table when the user clicks on a row.

How can this be done in "DataTables"?  I am very new to "DataTables" and JavaScript and would appreciated your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I'd use Datatables in this way. I've done something similar but rather than adding a table in a cell I've added a definition list... I think otherwise you're running the risk of making the table rather busy.

But if you're convinced that this is the way you want to go I'd look at the render call on the column and give is a function to create a table... or dl...

```
$("#myTable").DataTable({
    "data": data,
    "columns": [
        { 
            "title": "Name",
            "data": "name"
        }, { 
            "title": "Position",
            "data": "position" 
        }, { 
            "title": "Salary",
            "data": "salary" 
        }, { 
            "title": "Start Date",
            "data": "start_date" 
        }, { 
            "title": "Issue List",
            "data": "IssueList",
            "render": function(d){
                if(d !== null){
                    var table = "<table>";
                    $.each(d, function(k, v){
                        table += "<tr><td>" + v.Issue + "</td><td>" + v.IssueDate + "</td><td>" + v.Number + "</td></tr>";
                    });
                    return table + "</table>";
                }else{
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/LL2h0854/)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the response. I don't want to render inside a column, I was looking for a more master-detail table within the master table. I would like the "Issue" data render as  a separate table on the row below. The detail would show on mouse hover.

Comment: Ahh, looks like you'll be needing [row grouping](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html). The example will need tweaking though as it looks as though your data sometimes has top level entries without an `IssueList` and the example looks at creating rows using what would be your `IssueList` data. Another approach might be to use [Sliding child rows](http://www.datatables.net/blog/2014-10-02) - that might work better!